# Configure HTML body on drop down select

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular and typescript; I am developing an application that lets you edit three fields namely **SET1**, **SET2**, **SET3** on selecting the dropdown menu.

Example: I have 3 items in the drop-down menu: `menu-1`, `menu-2`, and `menu-3`, each menu has 3 different tabs namely `SET1`, `SET2`, `SET3`.

So when I click on menu-1 from the drop-down then I can edit **SET1**, **SET2**, **SET3** which belongs to **menu-1**.

So far I have been able to develop the **SET1**, **SET2**, **SET3** tabs but I am unable to know how do I add dropdown, and the **SET1**, **SET2**, **SET3** will change accordingly.

**My HTML file:**

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-1">SET-1</label>
    <div class="content">
      
      <p>
        <h2>A prime number</h2>Write a Java program to check if a given number is prime or not. Remember, a prime number is a number which is not divisible by any other number, e.g. 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, etc. 
        Be prepared for cross, e.g. checking till the square root of a number, etc.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-2">SET-2</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p><h2>String Palindrome</h2>You need to write a simple Java program to check if a given String is palindrome or not. A Palindrome is a String which is equal to the reverse of itself, e.g., "Bob" is a palindrome because of the reverse of "Bob" is also "Bob."  Though be prepared with both recursive and iterative solution of this problem.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-3">SET-3</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p><h2>Integer Palindrome</h2>This is generally asked as follow-up or alternative of the previous program. This time you need to check if given Integer is palindrome or not. An integer is called palindrome if it's equal to its reverse, e.g. 1001 is a palindrome, but 1234 is not because the reverse of 1234 is 4321 which is not equal to 1234. You can use divide by 10 to reduce the number and modulus 10 to get the last digit. This trick is used to solve this problem.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Each Set contains atleast three question, select the sets from the drop down list and then edit the question given</p>
```

---

**My CSS file:**

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
    clear: both;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .tab {
    float: left;
  }
  .tab label {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
  }
  .tab [type="radio"] {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .content > * {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
  }
  [type="radio"]:focus ~ label {
    ouline: 2px solid blue;
  }
  [type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  [type="radio"]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  [type="radio"]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
```

---

**My .ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questions-set',
  templateUrl: './questions-set.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questions-set.component.css']
})
export class QuestionsSetComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

}
```

---

My work till now: http://jsfiddle.net/zgua05mk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a variable in the component.ts file like clicked or where-ever you want and use a method do check it, for example:

```
<div id="example" (click)="checked()>
```

in your ts:

```
checked(){
this.clicked=true;
}
```

and last in your html (with the div) use the *ngIf operator to see if the variable is checked (the user clicked on the div):

```
<div id="show whatever you want after the click" *ngIf="clicked==true">
//the code you need to show after user interation
```